# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

He estado trabajando en este proyecto desde hace 3 dias, es lo de menos.

Soy nuevo en Netbeans, y me ha costado adaptarme, apenas se crear un proyecto y abrirlo.

Ayer, cuando probe por ultima ves mi proyecto, se podia abrir perfectamente (es una calculadora) y hoy, que acabo de seguir, le quise probar, sin realizar ningun cambio, y noto ese error.

El codigo es muy largo, pero intentare poner lo importante.

```
package Paquete;

/**
 *
 * @author (anonimo)
 */
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Ventana
     */
    
    public float number1;
    public float number2;
    public String outcome;
    String txt = "", txtf = "";
    int Caractheres = 0, since = 0, until = 0, txt2 = 0;
    Ventana vn = new Ventana();
    
    
    public Ventana() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton16 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton17 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton19 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton20 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton21 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton22 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton23 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton24 = new javax.swing.JButton();
```

**En el static void main**:

```
   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton14;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton15;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton16;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton17;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton19;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton20;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton21;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton22;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton23;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton24;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
   private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
   private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
   private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
   private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
```

Dudo mucho que el error sea los botones, o el panel, o lo relacionado, pero es que no le modifique nada del jFrame, o no se cual es el erro.

Si me pueden ayudar a ver si el error es del static void, o algo asi, Gracias!

**MUCHAS GRACIAS, El problema era que habia lo siguiente**

```
Ventana vn = new Ventana();
```

Al parecer era innecesario, pero gracias!

Comment: Parece que está ocurriendo un desbordamiento de la pila, por un bucle infinito o algo parecido. Revisa la traza del error, cerca a donde dice *`Caused by ...`* ahí te dirá exactamente donde ocurre el problema, pon si quieres esa parte en la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya vi el problema